# Rails, one-to-many relationship error in rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, one-to-many

I need to set up a one to many relationship between my "Teacher" model and my "Robot" model. Each teacher has many robots but each robot only has one teacher.

I thought I had it set up properly but when I try to play around with it in rails console typing this:

```
teacher1.robots = [robot1, robot2]
```

where teacher1 is a valid teacher and robot1 and robot2 are both valid robots, yields this error:

```
SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: robots.teacher_id: SELECT "robots".* FROM "robots"  WHERE "robots"."teacher_id" = 14
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: robots.teacher_id: SELECT "robots".* FROM "robots"  WHERE "robots"."teacher_id" = 14
```

I am very new to Ruby (and Ruby on Rails) but in all the research I've done, I can't find any mistake in the way I've set up my models or migrations... Here are the two model files and the migration.

*_create_robots.rb:

```
class CreateRobots < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
      create_table 'robots' do |t|
          t.text    'serial'
          t.references 'teachers'
      end
  end
  def down ; drop_table 'robots' ; end
end
```

robot.rb:

```
class Robot < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :teacher
end
```

teacher.rb:

```
class Teacher < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :robots

before_destroy :confirm_no_inventory
protected
def confirm_no_inventory
    unless self.usb_cords == 0 and self.simple_snaps == 0 and self.casters == 0
        errors.add(:base, "All checked out items must be returned before #{self.name} can be deleted")
        return false
    end
end
end
```

Thank you in advance to anyone who took the time to look through this, any thoughts at all on what the problem is or how to fix it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you actually run the migration? `rake db:migrate`

Comment: yep, I ran it twice and made sure no changes occurred the second time I ran it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `references` helper must be used with a **singular** model name. You used the plural `teachers` which resulted in a column called `teachers_id` which Active Record can't find.

Roll back your migration, change it to show the following and re-run:

```
t.references 'teacher'
```